# javascript array and mysql

Tags: javascript, sql

```
        var day = new Array();
     $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
     day.push($(this).val());
      });
       alert(day);
```

which return this:

[image]

but I would like to get this:

```
`3`,`10`,`16`
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
day.push('`' + $(this).val() + '`');
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was trying to do for 2 hours. I will accept the answer in 8 min... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is in an array.  Alerts just show arrays differently.  try looking at it in `console.log()` you will see